# Restoring password of a WIndows hosted network

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, netsh

I have created a hosted network in my windows7 system. The `netsh wlan show hostednetwork` command gives the output

```
Hosted network settings
-----------------------
    Mode                   : Allowed
    SSID name              : "rambo"
    Max number of clients  : 100
    Authentication         : WPA2-Personal
    Cipher                 : CCMP

Hosted network status
---------------------
    Status                 : Started
    BSSID                  : xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
    Radio type             : 802.11n
    Channel                : 11
    Number of clients      : 1
        xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx        Authenticated
```

But I have forgot the password for this connection and after some googling I found the command `netsh wlan refresh hostednetwork YourNewNetworkPassword`. But on executing this command it get the error

```
C:\Users\user>netsh wlan refresh hostednetwork rambo123
Invalid value "rambo123" for command option "data".

Usage: refresh hostednetwork [data=]key
```

I have no idea what is wrong with this command.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could reset your password by setting the whole network up again ie (via [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd815243%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)):

> `netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=rambo key=rambo123 keyUsage=persistent`

or

> `netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=rambo key=rambo123 keyUsage=temporary`

***Although,*** if you've forgotten your password, all you need to do is (via [here](http://mickspace.net/Win7Vwifishare/)):

> `netsh wlan show hostednetwork setting=security`

Then you'll see `User security key:` and your password

[image: Command prompt with netsh]

Comment: thanks @shub `setting=security` worked perfectly.

Comment: any idea what was wrong  with the `refresh hostednetwork` command... Its still haunting me.

Comment: @NandakumarV I'm sorry, I don't know. Although when I tested, this worked: `netsh wlan refresh hostednetwork key` which makes me think that `refresh` actually refreshes the key ie. makes sure it works rather than actually change it because `key` is the 'name' of the password field. Please +1 if you found the answer helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this format:

`netsh wlan set hostednetwork [ssid=]<ssid> [key=]<passphrase> [keyUsage=]persistent|temporary` ([Source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744890(v=ws.10).aspx#bkmk_wlanRefresh))

So to permanently set the Rambo network's passphrase to "rambo123" it'd be something like:

`netsh wlan set hostednetwork rambo rambo123 persistent`

Comment: In the Windows command-line world, things in `[]` are optional, that's why they're there. :)